# How to calculate all possible resistances made from 5 distinct resistors in series and/or parallel?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, programming, combinatorics

Five distinct resistors `resistors={1,2,3,4,5}` are given. The objective is to find a list of all possible resistances obtained by configuring all these resistors in any series and/or parallel forms.

How can I do with Mathematica?

Comment: What version of Mathematica do you use?

Comment: Of your question, the title asks for the configurations (i.e. circuits) and the body asks just for their resistances.  Which do you want?

Comment: Series and parallel are not the only way resistors can be connected. You can also do this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hhe4.png  Once you have all graphs generated, computing the resistance is easy. You'll need to use `IncidenceMatrix` and write equations for: currents summing to 0 in all nodes; current-voltage relationship; use the potential at each node to compute potential differences for each edge.  **Thus the difficult part is generating all valid graphs.**

Comment: @MichaelE2: The resistance is the most required.

Comment: @Szabolcs You are correct!

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@Groupings[Permutations@{r1, r2, r3, r4, r5}, {Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}] &} -> 2]`? Note that this method does not take into account `Flat`ness and `Orderless`ness of series and parallel connections during `Groupings` generation, there are a lot of duplicates initially generated and deleted afterwards, so it won't scale well to larger numbers of resistors.

Comment: `Orderless`ness actually can be to some extent taken into account: `DeleteDuplicates@Groupings[Permutations@{r1, r2, r3, r4, r5}, {Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}] &} -> {{2, Orderless}}]`.

Comment: You have not actually clarified if you only want series/parallel arrangement or all possible connectivity patterns.  Please make this explicit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Any connection of resistors in series and/or parallel can be seen as a tree in which branch nodes are connection types and leaves are resistors.

Series connection of a resistor with series connection of two other resistors is just a series connection of all three resistors, in other words series connection is described by an associative (or [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html)) branch node. Same is true for parallel connection.

Series or parallel connection of one resistor with second one is the same thing as connection of second one with first one, so connections are described by commutative (or [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html)) branch nodes.

---

## Groupings

To generate all necessary trees we can use [`Groupings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings.html) function.

Since series and parallel connections are `Flat`, we can limit ourselves to generating binary trees, so we'll use `2` as branch arity.

`Groupings` function groups subsequences of given list and we need not only subsequence groupings but all subset groupings, so as first argument we'll use `Permutations` of set of resistors.

With `Permutations` of resistors, as first argument, we don't need more than one representative for each collection of expressions whose tree structure is equivalent up to permutation of the branches, so we can use `{2, Orderless}` as arity specification.

Putting it together we get 472 combinations:

```
DeleteDuplicates@Groupings[
    Permutations@{r1, r2, r3, r4, r5},
    {Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}] &} -> {{2, Orderless}}
] // Short
(* {r1+r2+r3+r4+r5, 1/(1/r1+1/r2)+r3+r4+r5, r2+1/(1/r1+1/r3)+r4+r5,
    r2+r3+1/(1/r1+1/r4)+r5, <<465>>, 1/(1/r1+1/r2+1/r4+1/(r3+r5)),
    1/(1/r1+1/r2+1/r3+1/(r4+r5)), 1/(1/r1+1/r2+1/r3+1/r4+1/r5)} *)
% // Length
(* 472 *)
```

After flattening many binary groupings can give same grouping with higher arity. Also we start with all permutations of resistors, so we'll end up with many groupings that differ only by permutations of resistors within node, so for orderless connection they describe same system. That's why initially we get a lot of duplicates in our list:

```
Groupings[
    Permutations@{r1, r2, r3, r4, r5},
    {Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}] &} -> {{2, Orderless}}
] // Length
(* 5760 *)
```

That's why this approach won't scale well to larger numbers of resistors.

---

## orderlessTrees

To remedy problems mentioned above we can directly generate all relevant "orderless trees".

```
ClearAll[orderlessTrees, hold, extendOrderlessTreeBranchAt, extendOrderlessTrees]
SetAttributes[{hold, extendOrderlessTreeBranchAt, extendOrderlessTrees}, HoldAllComplete]

extendOrderlessTreeBranchAt[tree_, leaf_] := Function[Null,
  ReplaceList[
    First@Extract[tree, {#}],
    {
      hold[pre___, x_, post___] :> ReplacePart[tree, {#} -> hold[pre, hold[x, leaf], post]],
      l_hold :>  ReplacePart[tree, {#} -> Append[l, Unevaluated@leaf]]
    }
  ],
  HoldAllComplete
]

extendOrderlessTrees[trees_, leaf_] := Flatten[
  Function[Null,
    {
      {{hold[#, leaf]}},
      extendOrderlessTreeBranchAt[#, leaf] /@ Position[#, _hold, Heads -> False]
    },
    HoldAllComplete
  ] /@ trees,
  3
]

orderlessTreesInternal = Function[Null,
  Fold[extendOrderlessTrees, {hold[#1, #2]}, Unevaluated@{##3}],
  HoldAllComplete
];

orderlessTrees@_[] = {};
orderlessTrees[l : _@_] := {l}
orderlessTrees[h_@x__] := Identity[With][{hold = h}, Evaluate@orderlessTreesInternal@x]
```

Now we can directly generate all relevant for us groupings:

```
orderlessTrees@Range@3
(* {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 3}, 2}, {1, {2, 3}}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

not only ordered subsequence groupings:

```
Groupings[Range@3, {2, 3}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {1, {2, 3}}} *)
```

nor groupings with duplicates coming from all permutations:

```
Groupings[Permutations@Range@3, {{2, Orderless}, {3, Orderless}}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1},
   {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 3}, 2}, {{2, 1}, 3}, {{2, 3}, 1}, {{3, 1}, 2}, {{3, 2}, 1}} *)
```

Since nodes representing our connections are `Flat`, directly inside series node there can be only parallel nodes (or "bare" resistors) and vice versa. So single "orderless tree" can be transformed into two connections. One with nodes on odd levels representing series connections and nodes on even levels - parallel connections, and one with series connections on even levels and parallel on odd levels.

We can perform above transformation by `Fold`ing `Apply` function.

```
seriesParallelResistances // ClearAll
seriesParallelResistances[l : {_}] := l
seriesParallelResistances[l : {rs__}] := Module[
  {testQ, levels = Range[Length@l - 1, 1, -1], trees = orderlessTreesInternal@rs},
  Table[
    Sequence @@ Fold[Apply[If[testQ@#2, Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}]&], #1, {#2}] &, trees, levels],
    {testQ, {OddQ, EvenQ}}
  ]
]
```

Using `seriesParallelResistances` we get the same resistances as with `Groupings`:

```
seriesParallelResistances@{r1, r2, r3}
(* {1/(1/r1 + 1/r2) + r3, r2 + 1/(1/r1 + 1/r3), r1 + 1/(1/r2 + 1/r3),
   r1 + r2 + r3, 1/(1/(r1 + r2) + 1/r3), 1/(1/r2 + 1/(r1 + r3)),
   1/(1/r1 + 1/(r2 + r3)), 1/(1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3)} *)
Sort@% === Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Groupings[Permutations@{r1, r2, r3}, {Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}] &} -> {{2, Orderless}}]
(* True *)
```

but faster and using less memory:

```
tmp = {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5};
res1 = seriesParallelResistances@tmp; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
res2 = DeleteDuplicates@Groupings[Permutations@tmp, {Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}] &} -> {{2, Orderless}}]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
Sort@res1 === Sort@res2
(* {0.0060, 328800} *)
(* {0.174, 5055352} *)
(* True *)

tmp = {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6};
res1 = seriesParallelResistances@tmp; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
res2 = DeleteDuplicates@Groupings[Permutations@tmp, {Plus, 1/Total[1/{##}] &} -> {{2, Orderless}}]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
Sort@res1 === Sort@res2
(* {0.0871, 4611032} *)
(* {5.25, 147111488} *)
(* True *)
```